# Binding a model property to a List<SelectListItem> on Post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post the value of the textbox that is clicked, back to the controller. My problem is, no matter what textbox is clicked, the form only posts back the first item within the list. I know I could've used a dropdownlist instead but I ultimately decided against it.

I've got a view where I'm looping through a `List<SelectListItem>`. Within this loop, I'm creating a textbox for another model property(`string`) and setting the value of the property to an item within the `List<SelectListItem>`. I've set the textboxes as readonly and added jquery to submit the form when a textbox is clicked.

The commented JQuery which posts the value of the textbox to the console works fine. It's posting back to the controller where I'm having the issue. I think the problem might be because the JQuery postback is not recognising each individual textbox and instead posts the first item in the list - I might be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the view:

```
 @model TheConnector.ViewModel.SelectAHero
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Heroes";
        ViewBag.Message = "Here are the Heroes that are currently registered with your account";
    }
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.postHeroSelection').click(function () {
                    $(this).closest('form').submit();
                });
            });


    //        $(document).ready(function () {
    //            $('.postHeroSelection').click(function () {
    //                console.log($(this).val());
    //            });
    //        });


        </script>
    }
    <noscript>
        <style>
            body
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=javascript-error.htm" />
    </noscript>
    <div class="full grey_bg auto-height">
        <!-- Full -->
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="container" style="background-color: #ddd">
                <div style="padding: 0px; border: 0px solid black; height: 100px; margin: 0; padding: 10px;">
                    <div style="float: left; border: 0px solid black; padding: 0 0; height: 100%; display: table;">
                        <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
                <div id="RegisterNewHero">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Heroes", "User", FormMethod.Post))
                    {

                        <h3>
                            Please click on one of the following to load a Hero:</h3>
                        <br />

                        for (var i = 0; i < Model.ListOfHeroes.Count; i++)
                        { 
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.chosenHero, new { @class = "postHeroSelection", onclick = "return false", @Value = Model.ListOfHeroes[i].Value.ToUpper(), @readonly = "readonly", @id = Model.ListOfHeroes[i].Value })
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        }

                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />

                    }
                </div>
                <!-- Register -->
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / Content -->
        </div>
        <!-- Full  -->
    </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
            [Authorize]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Heroes(SelectAHero model) {

             if(ModelState.IsValid){

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }
        else
{     
                 ModelState.AddModelError("","An error has occurred");

             return View(model);
             }
}
```

Comment: So you want all the values of the textboxes in the post method right???

Comment: @GaganDeep I would like the value of whichever textbox that is clicked to be posted back

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry, now i understand your code.
you need add this code in your form.

```
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.chosenHero)
```

and change your script to

```
            $('.postHeroSelection').click(function () {

                document.getElementById("chosenHero").value = $(this).val();// add this line 
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });
```

now you can access model.chosenHero.

and change your textbox list to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ListOfHeroes[i].Value
                                        , new {
                                            @class = "postHeroSelection"
                                            , onclick = "return false"
                                            , @readonly = "readonly"
                                            , @id = Model.ListOfHeroes[i].Value
                                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one form so this "$(this).closest('form').submit();" is unnecessary. You can see what you post by looking to browsers network section(developer tool).

You can basically use `<a href="Heroes?id=@yourHeroId">` to pass selected data without using form or js.

And your Controller look like

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Heroes(string id){ //whatever you do}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always post first item with the correspondent name of the form to server.
You'll need an auxiliar element (Hidden maybe) to store the value clicked.

In my personal opnion is preferable use DropDownListFor that was created for this purpose.